# Button which is not runat server triggers all validators on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

Firstly before we go anywhere please don't worry about javascript in your answer. Client side validation is working as expected and I have turned off javascript in my browser to focus on testing server side validation. OK!

I have a webforms user control which has input fields and validators. But due to the specific HTML and CSS design I have been given, I can't use an <asp:Button> control it is necessary for me to use a html <button type="submit"> to submit the form. This is *Not* the same as <asp:Button> which renders as <input type="submit">

I have tested my html <button> tags in all the browsers I need to support and they are working. In my Page_Load I can determine which button has been clicked and trigger the correct validation group, and then if validation passes, run the right method.

Unfortunately when I click a button, *all* the validators in all the user controls in all the validation groups get triggered server-side! I was expecting none of the validators to be triggered so that I can use Page.Validate server-side. Has anyone seen this behaviour? Is there a known solution?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Are you setting the button type? By default it's submit, which, under most circumstances, *should* trigger validation.

Comment: Yes I am setting the button type to submit because I want to submit the form. Firing all validators seems to be the behaviour... but is there a way to change this behaviour because it isn't desirable when there is more than 1 validation group?